# What is the equivalent of this linux command to powershell

Tags: linux, powershell

> source scripts\set_env_vars_development.sh

I am trying to deploy django web framework from linux to windows powershell and that is one of the command.

Comment: The equivalent of `source` is dot-sourcing, `. c:\path\to\file.ps1` (with a space after the dot).  Sourcing the content of a Bash script into a running PowerShell session makes no sense.

Comment: Why the trailing space after dot?  never mind.  Answer explains.

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell does not have a `source`, but the equivalent is called [dot sourcing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts?view=powershell-5.1&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-Microsoft.PowerShell.Core) (header: "SCRIPT SCOPE AND DOT SOURCING"):

```
PS C:\>. scripts\set_env_vars_development.ps1
```